# Compatibility issues with <a> and calling a function(); across different web browsers

Tags: function, anchor

I am new to javascript. I wrote the following function rollDice() to produce 5 random numbers and display them. I use an anchor with click event to call the function. Problem is, in Chrome it won't display, works fine in IE, in firefox the 5 values display and then the original page w/anchor appears! I am suspicious that my script tag is too general but I am really lost. Also if there is a display function that doesn't clear the screen first that would be great.

diceArray = new Array(5)

function rollDice()
{
 var i;

for(i=0; i<5; i++)
 {
  diceArray[i]=Math.round(Math.random() * 6) % 6 + 1;

document.write(diceArray[i]); 
 }
}

when I click should display 5 rand variables

Comment: I think the problem is probably in your HTML. Are you putting your JavaScript in the head inline, or linked in a .js file? On your `<a>` tag, have you got `href='#'`?

Answer (score 0):

Do any errors appear in the Javascript consoles?  I know that Chrome and Firefox both have them, so you should be able to see if any errors are being generated.  You could also add a few alert('Hey') messages to check that it's even being launched in Chrome.

I do see that you don't have a semi-colon after your first line, but I don't know if that's a direct cut and paste, or if you typed it all in manually.